# Misterious Problems With CRM 4 Endpoint

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

there is a very strange issue with my CRM 4 Endpoint.

I use it, to edit fields on one custom entity. 
The connection is open and als methods are working fine.

Set a field to empty in the custom entity object, and then call the update method, all modifications have been changed. But only in the database!

If I refresh the form, the old value is returned to database..
How can that be possible?
There is no JS or Plug-In active..

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the execute, updaterequest message and the custom entity as dynamic entity.